# How can I make a button, like a target, move in a set div when it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a basic aim trainer game. I have a gameboard which is just a div with a range and a target icon which is really just a button. I want the button to move inside the range every time it is clicked.

This is my code for the gameboard and target

```js
function targetClicked() {
    score++;
    document.getElementById("scoreLabel").innerHTML = score;

    moveTarget();
}

function moveTarget() {

}
```

```css
#gameboard {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;

    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: darkgray;

}

#target {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;

    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="gameboard">
  <input hidden type="image" src="target.png" id="target" onclick="targetClicked()">
</div>
```

Everything else such as the countdown timer and score counter work. (not shown here) I even got the gameboard and everything to disappear when the counter reaches 0, but I don't actually know how to move the target every time it is clicked.

Can I used something like this and inside the moveTarget function adjust the property of the buttons location?

Is there a better way to go about it or can I simply make the button move its position when its clicked?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this. You could set the `style` of your `target` element on click and use the `transform` property you're already using above to set the position of the target. For example:

```js
      function getRandomInt(max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
      }

      function targetClicked() {
        const randX = getRandomInt(100);
        const randY = getRandomInt(100);
        document.getElementById("target").style.transform = `translate(${randX}%, ${randY}%)`;
      }
```

If you'd like to know more you may want to look at all the different ways position can be set via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

By this you can move the image any where inside the parent element.

```js
function randomAxis(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
const img = document.getElementById("gameboard_target");
const gameboard = document.getElementById("gameboard").getBoundingClientRect();
const img_credentials = img.getBoundingClientRect();
const g_width = gameboard.width-img_credentials.width;
const g_height = gameboard.height-img_credentials.height;
img.onclick = function(){
        const y_axis = randomAxis(0,g_width);
        const x_axis = randomAxis(0,g_height);
        this.style.cssText = `transform:translate(${x_axis}px,${y_axis}px)`
};
```

```css
#gameboard{
    border:2px solid;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: darkgray;
}
#gameboard img{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: transform .5s cubic-bezier(.22,.61,.36,1);
    cursor:pointer;
}

#gameboard img:active{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 3px #ecebeb;
}
```

```html
 <div id="gameboard">
        <img id="gameboard_target" src="https://justinmonserrat.github.io/target-practice/target.png" />
    </div>
```